# .htmlの内容を、事前のalert動作有無次第で捉えられない、なんてことはありますか（JQuery）

Tags: javascript, jquery

皆様　いつも大変お世話になっております。
====質問====
Alert文の有無だけで、動作が変わってくる（配列の変数の内容が変わってくる？）ことなどあり得るか？あるとした場合、どういうケースで起こるか？

====詳細====
以下コーディングにあるdowntotalCalc関数が、初回に呼ばれた際のみ期待動作をしてくれません。
その関数内で、動作させたい根幹部分前に、Alert文を記載すると、無事根幹部分を通過します。しかしAlert文をコメントアウトすると、根幹部分を通過してくれません！！
Alert文自体は、現在生じている『初回だけ根幹部分を通過しない』要因を特定するためのものです。根幹部分に入る・入らないは、変数の値が設定されている・されてないの条件式で作用するようコーディングしています。
しかしAlert文の有無だけで現在動作が変わってきてしまっているので、配列の変数内容の設定がこれにリンクして行われているの？と疑ってしまった私です。

Table明細上のINPUT=数量枠に値が入ったら、同明細のラベル列にDBからの単価を表示（Ajax）、また別のラベル列には数量に単価を乗じ金額を表示。
Tableの末端部分には合計覧が存在するので、こちらに明細の金額総合計を表示したい、というのが狙いです。（これがされない）

元をたどれば、Ajaxで達成される明細中の単価取得に関連した動きなので、やはりこれが起因しているのでしょうか？setTimerとかで逃げられる事象なのでしょうか．．．

```
//数量のテキストボックスからフォーカスが外れたら
$("input[name=amount]").on("blur",function() {

    //【省略】　Table明細上の数量枠(INPUT)に値が入ったら、横のラベルに金額を表示

    //【問題の関数へ】上記動作（変化）と併せ、Table末端部分に、総合計を表示したい！！ 
    downtotalCalc();
});


//問題の関数（実験中）
function downtotalCalc () {
    var $totalp = $("label[name=totalp]");

    console.log($totalp);
//$$    alert("###今夜が山田①###");  //【当該関数１回目の動作がこの行次第で変わってくる、下のFor文が通過しない】
    //１行目は非表示になっているため指数[１]でループ開始
    for (var i = 1; i < $totalp.length; i++) {
        if ($totalp.eq(i).html() != "" && $totalp.eq(i).html() != 0 && $totalp.eq(i).html() != "0") {
            alert("###今夜が山田② [" + i + "] ###");
        }
    }
    alert("###今夜が山田③###");
}
```

Comment: Ajaxによるデータ取得が完了した後の実行であるかどうかは確認していますか？

Comment: downtotalCalc();の呼び出し部分では、Ajaxによるデータ取得が完了した・していないの検知はしていません。
明細上の数量枠が0に修正された場合でも（DB参照せず金額列をクリア=非Ajax）、合計覧の反映を達成したいと考えていた為でした。問題部分の条件式に用いられている変数は、同名で複数存在するラベル要素であり、配列の変数として格納しています。
以下コーディングにあるとおりcosole.logで確認を行っている（ブラウザの開発者ツール）のですが、Alert有無の動作違いで内容（innerHTML）に違いは見られないようでした。
このためAjaxに関連した項目といえ、現在達成したい動作には関係しないもの、と解釈して進めてきていました．．．やはりAjaxでしょうか
条件判断時の変数の内容を確認することなど　できないのでしょうかね？

Comment: 非同期(Ajaxなど)でAlertの処理とは別の処理が並列に走っていてAlertでブロックしている間に共有している値を上書きしてたりすることは有りませんか？Alert関数自体が何かの変数に対し値を変更することはラップしていない限りないです。

Comment: BLUEPIXY様・Myaku様　ご見解ありがとうございました、お蔭様で無事解決することができました。
先ほど自身で「明細上の数量枠が0に修正された場合でも（DB参照せず金額列をクリア=非Ajax）、合計覧の反映を達成したい為、Ajaxの完了検知はしていない」、とコメントしました。
考えてみれば、Ajaxを動作させた場合でも（単価をDBから取得）、単価を0にされた非Ajaxの動作でも、同じ関数を呼ぶようにすれば良いだけの話でした。
つまりAjax利用後では、やはりその検知が必須であることを、お二方の見解から気づくことができました。
重ねて御礼を申し上げます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントに自身で追記しましたが、Ajax利用後に関連した処理を実装する場合、その検知が必須であることをお二方の見解から気づくことができました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: 検知用に$.Deferred()というものがあることのを初めて知りました。
今回はAjax動作時と非動作の際両方に実行したい関数を動作させようとした課題で、Ajax動作時に実行したい場合の関数呼び出しを
.doneの範囲内で記載して一応に回避できました。

しかし皆様が検知しているの？と述べていたのは$.Deferred()のことを申されていたのかな？と今になって気がつきました。
（.doneのことではなく）
現在別件のAjax実装を対応しようとていて、学びました。（また分からないことが出てきてしまいました）